# read image permission in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to access images in a matlab interface
my code is as follows:

```
global  im2 im  
axes(handles.axes4); 

[path1, user_cance]= imgetfile();
if user_cance 
    msgbox(sprintf('Error'), 'Error', 'Error'); 

    return
end

srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\User\Desktop\images test\yale faces\yalefaces\..');    
 % yale faces is the database folder 

for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    file_name=dir(strcat('C:\Users\User\Desktop\images test\yale faces\yalefaces')); 

  im2=imread(strcat('C:\Users\User\Desktop\images test\yale faces\yalefaces',file_name(i).name));  
    %processing of read image

end
```

the issue is that when I run the code, it gives the following error:

> Can't open file "C:\Users\User\Desktop\images test\yale faces\yalefaces"  for
>   reading;
>   you may not have read permission.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: what's the output of `im2`? did you forget a backslash in your last `strcat`-call?

Comment: im2 is here used for  the image to be read (earlier I used im for the same purpose, as the interface consists of two axes)

Comment: It won't answer the question, but two things that can help you in the future: Avoid using global variables unless it is really neccesary (in nearly all situations they are considered bad practice in Matlab), always use `fullfile` to build file paths (rather than `strcat`).

Answer (score 4):

When you do a directory listing (without any wildcards) you are going to get the current directory `'.'` and parent directory as well `'..'`. You can't read these like files because they are directories. You will need to filter out the directories prior to trying to read them with imread.

```
files = dir('C:\Users\User\Desktop\images test\yale faces\yalefaces'); 

% Remove directories
files = files(~[files.isdir]);
```

As a side note, it is very hard to tell what your code is doing, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do what you hope.

It seems like you want to get all images within the database. If that's so, you'll want to do something like.

```
folder = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\images test\yale faces\yalefaces';

% Get a list of all files in this folder
files = dir(folder);
files = files(~[files.isdir]);

for k = 1:numel(files)
    % Append the folder with the filename to get the path and load
    im2 = imread(fullfile(folder, files(k).name));
end
```

I highly discourage using `strcat` to construct file paths particularly because it removes trailing/leading whitespace from each input which can corrupt a filename. `fullfile` was designed for exactly this so please use that.

Comment: To validate that this is the problem, one could run the code with `dbstop if error` and inspect `file_name(i).name`.

Comment: Suever sorry for the late reply; thanx for your help, I'm starting to understand more about it; just to ask, can I use  the code you provided as it is (  to fetch the images in a looping sequence) ?